# What's the difference between maven building and forking a project in a multi module build?

Tags: java, maven, build, maven-3

There's a maven multi module project with several nested levels. When I run

```
mvn clean install
```

some projects are build with the logging message

```
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building my-nested-maven-module-project-1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

and some other (in a directory having many modules) with the logging message:

```
[INFO] >>> maven-assembly-plugin:2.4:assembly (default) @ bm-ds-master-database >>>
[INFO]                                                                         
[INFO] >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>
[INFO] Forking my-maven-module-among-many-1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>
```

Forking built projects are giving me a headache by not calling mvn-install-plugin on built jars, thus not copying some of them to the local maven repository.

Comment: Usually a _forked_ build is initiated by a plugin in your build, that needs to be sure some phases are executed before it can work. Surely that should not prevent your _main_ build to execute, installing these modules in the end.

Comment: Which plugin does the forking of the life cycle?

Comment: It seems the assembly plugin

Answer (score 1):

As Brian Mathews in his blog "[Stuff I don't want to forget (again!)](http://blog.btmatthews.com/?p=66)" said, the problem is caused by the assembly plugin misconfiguration. Instead of using `assembly` goal it should be configured to get executed in the goal `single`. This goal doesn't initiate forked builds that are skipping installing files in the local maven repository.